# Adding elements of a struct into a list<type>

Tags: c#, list, struct, webobjects

Sorry if this has been asked before, as I am new to C#.

My question is how do I add elements of a struct to a list

I have a class Application variables that contains a struct of static strings.
Now I dont know how to add each element into a list of strings or even if this is possible.
However the being list string is being created in the presentation Layer.
I believe I need to new create a method, but not sure how to do this.

Thanks for your time.

```
public class ApplicationVariables
{
    public ApplicationVariables(){ }

    public struct HeaderName
    {
        public static string film ="Film";
        public static string director = "Director";
        public static string actor = "Actor";
        public static string filmYear = "Film Year";
        public static string imdbRating = "IMDB Rating";
    }
```

}

Comment: A struct of static strings does not make sense, just make it a static class.

Comment: reflection: you can see your classes members in runtime. use typeof(HeaderName).GetFields()

Comment: It is very likely you should not be using that to achieve what you actually want, but linked duplicate answers exact question *as asked*.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I will try this